# Symfony on Kubernetes - New Session is started on each request

Tags: php, symfony, session, kubernetes

Having an app running perfectly on my local with docker.

When I deploy it, I can't get why a new session is started on each request. It seems it can't come from the code since it's exactly the same.

The session is stored on a redis DB (I have the same bug if I use the filesystem session). It's there I can see all the new session created. (see last code block).

From the log I can clearly identify that the `$request->getSession()->getId()` changes on each request but not the PHPSESSID cookie.

For example:

*First request*

```
[2020-11-02 15:03:59] request.INFO: Matched route "app_login". {"route":"app_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::login"},"request_uri":"https://foo.bar.dev/login","method":"POST"} []
[2020-11-02 15:03:59] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2020-11-02 15:03:59] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2020-11-02 15:03:59] app.DEBUG: [LoginFormAuthenticator::supports] $request session id => 6491ddf4e8f3e2eaa22b44b3a98c094a [] []
[2020-11-02 15:03:59] app.DEBUG: [LoginFormAuthenticator::supports] $_COOKIE =>  {"PHPSESSID":"87cf6185b652f8d713c45031ebe6d8a4"} []
```

*Second one*

```
[2020-11-02 15:04:33] request.INFO: Matched route "app_login". {"route":"app_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::login"},"request_uri":"https://foo.bar.dev/login","method":"POST"} []
[2020-11-02 15:04:33] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2020-11-02 15:04:33] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2020-11-02 15:04:33] app.DEBUG: [LoginFormAuthenticator::supports] $request session id => 41b08dac8a803337a48dca7d5b33b840 [] []
[2020-11-02 15:04:33] app.DEBUG: [LoginFormAuthenticator::supports] $_COOKIE =>  {"PHPSESSID":"87cf6185b652f8d713c45031ebe6d8a4"} []
```

***KUBERNETES***

**ingress-nginx.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: secured-front
  namespace: foo-apis-dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: "persistent"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "PHPSESSID"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path: "/"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-samesite: "Lax"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800000"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - bar.foo.dev
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: bar.foo.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: bar-nginx
              servicePort: 80
            path: /(.*)
```

***Symfony APP***

**security.yaml**

```
[...]
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            pattern: ^/.*
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: login

            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
[...]
```

**services.yaml**

```
[...]
    Redis:
        class: Redis
        calls:
            - connect:
                  - '%env(REDIS_HOST)%'
                  - '%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%'

    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - '@Redis'
            - { prefix: 'admin_phpsess_' }
[...]
```

**packages.framework.yaml**

```
[...]
    session:
        handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax
[...]
```

**REDIS**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *admin*
1) "admin_phpsess_245e4a79fe35e2320943770061884c24"
2) "admin_phpsess_0ff29464322b3c2cfc5d8f5fd323ef75"
3) "admin_phpsess_26812c17f93a5d28a71853b77ac85386"
4) "admin_phpsess_7fbae6f0b1fdbe9576e41c9eee2cd60f"
```

VERSIONS:

- PHP 7.4.12
- Symfony 4.4
- Kubernetes 1.17.9
- redis (pecl) 5.3.2

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

The issue was about the redis configuration.

I took the step of using `PdoSessionHandler` and it works. The problem comes from Redis and / or Kubernetes, I have been trying for 2 hours to point out the configuration which generates this bug but impossible for now.

Comment: What are the values of the container parameter `framework.session.name` and the PHP INI config directive `session.name` in your case? Symfony falls back to the `session.name` directive in `php.ini` if `framework.session.name` is undefined. Is `/login` defined as an "anonymous" route in your firewall configuration aka. `security.yml` ?

Comment: if i dump a phpinfo i get => `session.name PHPSESSID`

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @BastienSander – have you ever figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Predis](https://github.com/predis/predis) session handler instead.

1. Setup your services

```yaml
# services.yaml
    Redis:
        class: \Predis\Client
        arguments:
            - 'redis://%env(REDIS_HOST)%:%env(REDIS_PORT)%'

    predis_session_handler:
        class: 'Predis\Session\Handler'
        arguments:
            - '@Redis'
```

2. Configure Symfony

```yaml
# framework.yaml
framework:
  session:
    handler_id: predis_session_handler
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path: "/"` to instead of the `/(.*)` regex.

Symfony's default parameter for the `framework.session.cookie_path` is `/`, too. ([documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-path))

Further change `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name` to  `"INGRESSCOOKIE"` or omit the annotation.

The session cookie of the nginx ingress is used to determine which pod the initial request was routed to and route any further requests to the exact same pod.

It's a different session cookie than the one of the PHP session and therefore should have a different cookie name. The ingress session cookie get's created and does likely overwrite the php session cookie with your configuration.

If you're using a redis session there should be no need to route continuous requests to the same pod in the cluster.

Comment: I changed to cookie-name. Still have the same issue.
Even with both headers :
`set-cookie: INGRESSCOOKIE=87cf6185b652f8d713c45031ebe6d8a4; Expires=Sun, 22-Nov-20 15:46:55 GMT; Max-Age=1728000; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.12`
`set-cookie: PHPSESSID=3931389ee24b9d42b9a06af0c0f1692f; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax`

Comment: Did you clear your cookies and validate - with your current configuration - the `Set-Cookie` handler does in fact make it through the ingress to your browser/client? Or is the `PHPSESSID` maybe just a leftover from previous requests/configurations?

Comment: Yes i cleared it.
Could it be the expiration ? which apperead as "Session" in firefox ?

Comment: Well there you have it `87cf6185b652f8d713c45031ebe6d8a4` is the ingress cookie session. Not the PHP one. It didn't change. Compare the session ID with a subsequent different route after the `POST` request to `/login`. At least at some point the `PHPSESSID` cookie was overwritten by the nginx ingress. That explains why PHP/symfony can't find that session id and opens a new one. Authenticating again might aswell give you a new session id. Therefore authenticate and access a route behind the firewall as the second request to test for the correct session id.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the PHPSESSID does change "randomly", I have sometimes after 10sec of a same session a header `set-cookie
 PHPSESSID=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax` in the response

Comment: what's the TTL of the redis session keys that get created by the `RedisSessionHandler`?

Comment: Any `delete_cookies:` directives in your firewall configuration? The issue of a `PHPSESSID=deleted` header being sent is a different - second - issue in this case. My answer definitely solved your first issue. Namely the php session cookie being overwritten by the ingress cookie.

Comment: When I log the redis monitor, I can see ` "SETEX" "admin_phpsess_XXX" "1440"`
I put my firewall on the question ;)

Comment: Well a redis TTL of (default) 1440 seconds might explain those quickly expiring sessions. If the session id is not found in redis anymore the cookie gets deleted. Makes sense. Update the redis sesion handlers `$options` argument to `- { prefix: 'admin_phpsess_', cookie_lifetime: 0 }` and clear your cache.

Comment: `1440` is the default value of PHP's `session.gc_lifetime` while the default for `session.cookie_lifetime` is `0`. What are the values of these PHP ini directives in your case?

Comment: Same => 1440 and 0

Comment: If i set cookie_lifetime in the redis handler I get ``The following options are not supported "cookie_lifetime".`

Comment: Change the framework / handler's cookie lifetime to `0` or some other value and check if the redis TTL changes accordingly. I'd recommend to try without without the `anonymous: lazy` directive for the `main` firewall.

Comment: The option key for the redis session handler is `ttl` instead of `cookie_lifetime`, sorry.

Comment: The issue was about the redis configuration.
I took the step of using PdoSessionHandler and it works.
The problem comes from Redis and / or Kubernetes, I have been trying for 2 hours to point out the configuration which generates this bug but impossible for now.